JOLT spec to perform group by ID and condition check on nested json
Please help me to provide a JOLT spec for the below input JSON. Tried multiple approaches but still not working. There is a condition check on the risk attribute; if the risk is "0," then the  risk level is low. If it is "1", then it is  High; if it is null, then it should be null. Only I got a solution, but for null value, the output JSON attribute is not showing.
Input JSON :
[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Manu",
    "age": 26,
    "location": "New York",
    "risk": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Manju",
    "age": 29,
    "location": "New York",
    "risk": null
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "sanju",
    "age": 24,
    "location": "New York city",
    "risk": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "Ramesh",
    "age": 23,
    "location": "India",
    "risk": null
  }
]

Expected JSON :
[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "location": "New York",
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "Manu",
        "age": 26,
        "riskLevel": "Low"
      },
      {
        "name": "Manju",
        "age": 29,
        "riskLevel": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "location": "New York city",
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "sanju",
        "age": 24,
        "riskLevel": "High"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "location": "India",
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "Ramesh",
        "age": 23,
        "riskLevel": null
      }
    ]
  }
]


You can use the following transformation
[ //set an arbitrary value(say "NUll") to a null valued "risk"
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "~risk": "NUll" //occures whnever risk is null due to the ~ operator 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,id.&[]", //the attributes other than the ones below
        "name|age": "@1,id.&1.&",
        "risk": {
          "1": { "#High": "@3,id.&3.riskLevel" }, //hardcode by # operator
          "0": { "#Low": "@3,id.&3.riskLevel" },
          "NUll": { "@": "@3,id.&3.riskLevel" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//nest some attributes with array "user" while pick the first occurence fron the newly formed "id" and "location" arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id|location": {
          "0": "&2.&1"
        },
        "*": "&1.user[]"
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the wrapper keys of "id" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]


Hi @Manjunath k , Can you please voteup as well, since only votingup increments the tag badge(s) and json and jolt tag badges are important for me, thanks in advance.

Thanks Barbaros for the awesome solution. I'm always learning form you and getting better in jolt because of your solutions. I would never knew that "~" has special meaning in jolt. May I ask how did you find out about it? is there url that you use for jolt guide that is comprehensive and has the latest?
Also if I may provide a different way for the spec:
[
  {
    //group user info under id & location
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "age": "@(1,id).@(1,location).[#2].age",
        "name": "@(1,id).@(1,location).[#2].name",
        "risk": {
          "0": {
            "#low": "@(3,id).@(3,location).[#4].risklevel"
          },
          "1": {
            "#high": "@(3,id).@(3,location).[#4].risklevel"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    // create final structure by
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$1": "[#3].id",
          "$": "[#3].location",
          // dont use array for users yet to avoid getting nulls from above  
          "*": "[#3].user"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    //ensure user is always an array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user": "MANY"
      }
    }
  }
  ,

  {
    // set risklevel to null by default if doesnt exist
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user[]": {
          "*": {
            "risklevel": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /**/
]

Also since I have been experiencing with jslt , I would like to provide a much abbreviated way of solving this using jstl:
import "http://jslt.schibsted.com/2018/experimental" as exp


    let groupBy= exp:group-by(.,
                                {"id":.id,"location":.location},
                                {"name":.name,"age":.age, "risklevel": if(.risk == "0") "low" else if (.risk=="1") "high" else null }
                              )
    let result = [for ($groupBy) {"id":.key.id,"location":.key.location,"user":.values}]
    
    $result 


Hi Samer, thank you, nice to hear such things. You can reach it through Questions tagged [jolt] ->  Learn More... -> Latest release: 0.1.6 -> Releases -> beneath the title v0.0.22 New Transform "modify" in beta state , good night !
